# Webpack require.ensure progress

Tags: reactjs, webpack, lazy-loading, code-splitting

I get blank screen for like 1 second delay especially once i opened the screen for the first time.

Is there a way I can trace the progress of the loaded module when using require.ensure?

Comment: What do you mean by "progress"? Download progress?